# Exception while changing Background Image of Activity Runtime

Tags: android

I am using the following lines of code to change the background image of my android activity at runtime :

         `private View mainLayout;  //global variable

     mainLayout = findViewById(R.layout.activity_breath); // getting the layout in onCreate method
     mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image); //this line is called in run method of timer.`

but I get a fatal error null pointer exception on my device when setBackgroundResource function is called. Can anyone please suggest a reason for failure??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to find a `R.layout` resource with `findViewById()` will always fail and return `null`. Use a `R.id` resource identifier that exists within your activity's view hierarchy.

Comment: Yes this did the job. Thanks